Terraform "local_file" does not write variable value into file, only after running it again
I have created a resource to write the public ip of a VM into a file.
The issue is that it does not write the "${local.my_ip}" value into the file, only if I specifically target the "local_file" again and run the playbook again.
I thought it might take some time for the IP address to be created, I have put 30s sleep after I run a custom script on the VM, but that also does not resolve the issue.
The "local_file"should be working, since if I specifically target that, it creates the file with "${local.my_ip}" value the without any issue.
resource "time_sleep" "sleep" {
  depends_on = [  azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.script]
  create_duration = "30s"
}
resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  filename="${path.module}/ansible_inventory"
  content = "[windows]\n${local.my_ip}"
  depends_on = [ time_sleep.sleep ]
}

